# How can I have my own customized UI in WSO2?

Tags: user-interface, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I wanted to use all the wso2 functionalities from my own customised UI. Is it possible to do so? If yes, them how to do it?

The scenario is: I don't want to use the available wso2 pages instead I wanted to have my own theme. How to do it?

Comment: Which UI/webapp are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about the customised HTML UI created by my own. 
I wanted to know: 
1. How to trigger the bpm from this UI?
2. How to complete the tasks assigned from the UI itself?

Basically, I want to control the wso2 features from my customised html UI.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 products up to carbon 4 are based on carbon osgi services. These services exposed as SOAP web services which known as admin services. You can refer WSO2 IS documentation to get idea how those can be enabled to outside and invoke [1]

You can create any application and invoke those SOAP web services. Although there are workarounds to invoke SOAP web services from HTML JS, best approach would be use a server side language like JSP and invoke web services from there. From front end HTML JS, you can use AJAX to call those JSP resources.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Calling+Admin+Services

Comment: How can I trigger the BPM from the customized html UI as a service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to your own UI like the BPMN explorer that ships with WSO2 BPS, you can use the BPMN REST api [1] for this. This documentation [2]explains how the existing UI works. You can build your own by invoking the Rest API.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/BPMN+REST+API

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Customizing+BPMN+Explorer